# Where can I report vulnerabilities to Google?

Tags: security, google, bugs

Where can I report glitches/bugs/vulnerabilities to google? I would look it up, but I don't know how to word it. Besides, I am working on more devices I can count (don't ask) and I have found some... Weaknessess in youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to [this page](https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new)
- Select option for reporting bug.
- Enter your contact details.
- Select Google Product as affected.
- Enter how to reproduce that vulnerability
- Submit It.

Google will contact you within day or two. If vulnerability is vaild and they successfully reproduce it you may get Bug Bounty.

Comment: That link is just for  security vulnerability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Settings → Developer options → Bug report.  If that doesn't exist, try holding both volume buttons plus Power (USB Debugging might need to be enabled).